# Display the most common word in the text

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, bufferedreader

I have a problem that I have been facing for two days.
I am given a text, which stretches over several lines and I have to display the most common word in the text, but the common words for example appear the same number of times in other words, to display the lexicographic minimum.
This is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map < String, Integer > map = new LinkedHashMap < String, Integer > ();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String currentLine = reader.readLine();
        while (currentLine != null) {
            String[] input = currentLine.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").toLowerCase().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                if (map.containsKey(input[i])) {
                    int count = map.get(input[i]);
                    map.put(input[i], count + 1);

                } else {
                    map.put(input[i], 1);
                }

            }
            currentLine = reader.readLine();
        }

        String mostRepeatedWord = null;
        int count = 0;
        for (Map.Entry < String, Integer > m: map.entrySet()) {
            if (m.getValue() > count) {
                mostRepeatedWord = m.getKey();
                count = m.getValue();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(mostRepeatedWord);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I find the lexicographic minimum?

Comment: Yes, I know how to compare lexicographically, but I did this only in c ++, in java using hashmap and all the functions in this language, I'm at the beginning and I don't really have a clear direction to compare in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison in Java follows a standard that is a little tricky at first — lexicographic comparison is no exception, but once you’ve understood how it goes, there is support for it that makes it pretty easy.

I suggest that in your for loop at the end, if the counts are equal, you compare the current word to `mostRepeatedWord`, and if it is smaller (comes before), you store it into `mostRepeatedWord`. For lexicographic comparison use `m.getKey().compareTo(mostRepeatedWord)` (or `m.getKey().compareToIgnoreCase(mostRepeatedWord)` if you want to ignore the difference between upper and lower case in the comparison). The method will return a negative number (any number strictly less than 0, it’s not specified which) if `m.getKey()` comes lexicographically before `mostRepeatedWord` (is smaller than it).

In this way, after your loop `mostRepeatedWord` holds the lexicographically smallest of the words appearing the most frequently (having the highest counts in the map).

And in case you were wondering if I’d write the code for you, no, you will learn a lot more by doing that yourself. If you steer into trouble, do follow up in comments, though, I will reply.

The documentation of the `compareTo` method says:

> **Returns:**
>
> the value 0 if the argument string is equal to this string; a value
>   less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string
>   argument; and a value greater than 0 if this string is
>   lexicographically greater than the string argument.

### Links

- [Documentation of `String.compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))
- [Java String compareTo() Method with examples](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-compareto-method-example/)
- [Documentation of the `Comparable` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) specifying the convention of `compareTo()` returning a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.